# how to get a value from templateField on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

how to get a value or text from templateField on gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Format">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Format" runat="server" 
       Text='<%#GetFormatText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, ("Format")))%>'> 
      </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The Value of grvRow.Cells[4] is always empty.

```
drpFormat.SelectedValue = grvRow.Cells[4].Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use FindControl to get the label in the templatefield

```
  Label lblname = (Label)grvRow.Cells[4].FindControl("Format");
  drpFormat.SelectedValue= lblname.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks mate Label formatText = (Label)grvRow.FindControl("FormatText");

Answer (score 0):

> you can also try like this

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("Format"));
string SelectedData =lbl.text;
```